# The misleading case of "could", "was able to"

Tags: modal-verbs

I'm a bit perplexed, if not lost.

Given "could" can't be used to describe a one-time ability and should be replaced by "was able to", such as in the following sentence:

> The burglar was able to (not **could**) get into the house through the window.

Then what makes the next sentence correct?

> I could see the look of disgust on her face.

I know it's fine, but according to the rule, shouldn't it be replaced by "was able to", since I was able to see the look on her face just on this one occasion?

And also, does the usage of time-related clauses, such as "yesterday", make the "was able to" form the only acceptable one?

> Because I've become fluent in German, yesterday I **could**/**was able to** come to an agreement with our foreign client.

And Another example:

> Once the riots in the prison started, I **could**/**was able to** escape, but decided to stay to avoid possible consequences.

Comment: "should be replaced"?  That's not a rule.  "The burglar could get into the house..." and "I could see the look... " are both perfectly well-written sentences.

Comment: So what's the differece between the two forms in my burglar example?

Comment: There's no difference; they are equivalent sentences.

Comment: There is a subtle difference which isn't worth-mentioning. Was able to/could are almost interchangeable in many cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second sentence below, with **could smash** is not valid paraphrase of the first, with **was able to smash**.

> The burglar was able to smash the window.
>
> The burglar could smash the window.<sup>ungrammatical in context</sup>

But here, the substitution of **could** for **was able** is not discordant to my ear:

> The toddler was able to chew solid food.
>
> The toddler could chew solid food.

The sentence about the burglar is understood to be an explanation for a break-in. The window was smashed. It happened. Being able to smash a particular window is not the same thing as being able to chew now that your molars are in. The ability to chew solid food is not a momentary, discrete ability as was the smashing of the window. In the same way, **seeing** is not a momentary discrete action but something that continues or persists.

> I was able to see the mountains in the distance.
>
> I could see the mountains in the distance.

And **could** can be substituted for **was able** when referring to the persistent or to the ongoing, to actions or events which are *not* over and done with the moment they take place.

We can easily introduce discord by choosing a verb that refers to an action that takes place all at once, **catch**:

> Rounding the corner, I was able to catch a glimpse of the mountains in the distance.
>
> Rounding the corner, I could catch a glimpse of the mountains in the distance.<sup>marginal</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that sheds some light on my problem. But still, I'm not sure which form I should choose in my last example, the one with the prison. Is my escape considered a discrete action, or is it ok to stick to "could"?

Comment: I think you're painting yourself into a corner there by avoiding the optimal choice of tense. You might say:  "I *could have escaped* once the riots in prison had started, but decided...."  or "Now that the riots had started, I could escape, but ..."  **Was able to** implies the escape took place (as **was** typically refers to a past actual not a past hypothetical) and then you reverse the meaning with "but".

Comment: And the German example? If I get it right, the "was able to" is more correct?

Comment: With the prison break, you're talking about a past hypothetical ("could have escaped"); with the German example, it seems you're talking about something which did indeed take place, a past actual: "Because I've become fluent in German I was able to strike a deal with our foreign client *yesterday*".  "Strike a deal" is like "catch a glimpse" or "come to an agreement" in terms of its being a discrete action in time.